# The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Before

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAbD0.png)I created a TestRunner class to run my test scenarios using Cucumber with JUnit.Inside stepDefination package, I created two classes i.e Hooks.java and stepDefination.java

1. [Hooks,java inside stepDefination package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pwwl.png)

The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Before.

2. Step Definition is giving error as:
   The import io.cucumber.java cannot be resolved.

**Pom has all the required dependencies as below:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>bdd</groupId>
  <artifactId>APIFramework</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>APIFramework</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>cucumber-jvm-example</projectName>
                            <!-- optional, per documentation set this to "true" to bypass generation of Cucumber Reports entirely, defaults to false if not specified -->
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                            <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jsonReports</inputDirectory>
                            <jsonFiles>
                                <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                                <param>**/*.json</param>
                            </jsonFiles>
                            <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->

                            <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                            <!-- optional, set true to group features by its Ids -->
                            <mergeFeaturesById>false</mergeFeaturesById>
                            <!-- optional, set true to get a final report with latest results of the same test from different test runs -->
                            <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>false</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
                            <!-- optional, set true to fail build on test failures -->
                            <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
  <dependencies>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0</version>

</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
</dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: U are using junit Before hook import. Use cucumber ones - `import io.cucumber.java.Before`

Comment: Also try and use one version for cucumber-* jars. u r using 5.7 for -core and 5.6 for -junit

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions @Grasshopper. I changed the above import statement and it worked while for your other suggestion, I have used same dependencies for core and junit(5.1.3) and that also worked. I am facing other problem which I will ask in other comment below.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62187173/i-am-unable-to-post-an-add-place-api-when-using-post-http-method                               @Grasshopper