# I am unable to post an Add Place API when using POST http method

Tags: json, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, rest-assured-jsonpath, grasshopper

> io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse
>   the JSON document

**It is throwing error in the code written for these Feature file steps:**

```
  Given  Add new location with "<name>" "<language>" "<address>" parameters
  Then  user calls "AddPlaceAPI" with http "POST" method  
  Then  API successful response with "status" as "OK"
```

**The stepDefinition  code for these steps**

```
     @Given("Add new location with {string} {string} {string} parameters")
    public void Add_new_location_with_three_parameters(String name_G,String address_G,String language_G) throws IOException {
        res=given().spec(requestSpecification())
                .body(data.googleAddPlace(name_G,address_G,language_G));

    }
    @Then("user calls {string} with http {string} method")
    public void user_calls_with_http_method(String resource_G,String http_method)
    {
        APIResources resourceAPI = APIResources.valueOf(resource_G);
        System.out.println("Resource value" + resourceAPI.getResource());
        resspec =new ResponseSpecBuilder().expectStatusCode(200).expectContentType(ContentType.JSON).build();
        if(http_method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST"))
                response= res.when().post(resourceAPI.getResource());

        else if(http_method.equalsIgnoreCase("GET"))
                response= res.when().post(resourceAPI.getResource());
    }


    @Then("API successful response with {string} as {string}")
    public void api_successful_response_with_as(String string, String string2) {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

        assertEquals(getJsonPath(response,string),string2);
    }
```

**`getJsonPath` method Definition where it is throwing Error**

```
public String getJsonPath(Response response,String key)
    {
            String resp=response.asString();
            JsonPath   js = new JsonPath(resp);
            return js.get(key).toString();
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyIqr.png)
**Junit Error Log**

> io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document
>    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:1002)
>    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4.doParseWith(JsonPath.java:967)
>    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$JsonParser.parseWith(JsonPath.java:1047)
>    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.get(JsonPath.java:202)
>    at resources.Utils.getJsonPath(Utils.java:56)
>    at stepDefinations.stepDefination.api_successful_response_with_as(stepDefination.java:117)
>    at ✽.API successful response with "status" as "OK"(file:///C:/Users/gaura/eclipse-workspaceNew/APIFramework/src/test/java/features/googlemapsValidation.feature:6)
>    Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading '<', no possible valid JSON value or
>   punctuation could be recognized.
>    at groovy.json.JsonLexer.nextToken(JsonLexer.java:86)
>    at groovy.json.JsonLexer$nextToken.call(Unknown Source)
>    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
>         at  io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parse(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:97)
>         at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper$parse.callCurrent(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
>         at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parseText(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:83)
>         at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4$1.method(JsonPath.java:965)
>         at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:1000)
>         at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4.doParseWith(JsonPath.java:967)
>         at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$JsonParser.parseWith(JsonPath.java:1047)
>         at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.get(JsonPath.java:202)
>         at resources.Utils.getJsonPath(Utils.java:56)
>         at stepDefinations.stepDefination.api_successful_response_with_as(stepDefination.java:117)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:27)
>         at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:27)
>         at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
>         at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:64)
>         at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:49)
>         at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:46)
>         at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:51)
>         at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:66)
>         at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:149)
>         at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:83)
>         at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:24)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
>         at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:185)
>         at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:83)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
>         at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$RunCucumber.evaluate(Cucumber.java:219)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)

Comment: Is this resolved ?

Comment: No, it is still not resolved. @Willfred Clement

Answer (score 0):

I tried combination of following versions for required jar files in pom.xml file and its working fine for me. You can also try the same:

1. JUnit-  version: 4.1.2
2. Cucumber - java - info.cukes - version: 1.2.4
3. Cucumber - junit - info.cukes - version: 1.2.3
4. Cucumber - pico container - info.cukes - version: 1.2.4
5. Cucumber - core - info.cukes - version: 1.2.6
6. Cucumber - jvm deps - info.cukes - version: 1.0.5
7. Rest Assurd - version: 3.0.2